# Regex in java which will accept following pattern

Tags: java, regex

My code is reading data from property file.
which may have following entries

rahul.**myServer2**.ip=192.168.0.4

I used following regex to fetch ip
rahul\.(\w+)\.ip

but my regex failed when i got

rahul.**myServer-1**.ip=192.168.0.3

now I need to write regex that will accept some special character also.
and it will return the values of **ip** and **myServername** 
whatever we will provide

Comment: `rahul\.([\w-_!@#]+)\.ip` you can give a bracket range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use this regex,

```
rahul\\.([\\w\\W]+?)\\.ip=([\\d.]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vJ1cP1/2)

Group 1 would contain the Server name and group  2 would contain the corresponding ip-address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negation based regex:

```
rahul\.([^.]+)\.ip
```

Here `[^.]+` will match 1 more characters until it gets a dot.

In Java you write that as:

```
rahul\\.([^.]+)\\.ip
```

Answer (score 0):

A good comprehensive approach would be `([^.]*)\\.[^.=]*=([\\d.]+)`, where group 1 will get the name and group 2 will get the ip.

It accept entries like:

```
myServer4.ip=192.168.0.5
rahul.middlename.myServer3.ip=192.168.0.4
rahul.myServer2.ip=192.168.0.3
```